# type 'List<void>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Client>>'

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I'm having issues simply printing what's inside a `DropdownButton` by looping the results of an API request that fetches the following:

```dart
[{id: 1, nome: foo}, ...]
```

This is the code for it.

```dart
return _response.data.map<Client>((i) => Client.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

Which oddly, when printing the variable that stores the above call is `[Instance of 'Client', ...]`

Then, in the view, I attempt to at least print each item:

```dart
DropdownButton<Client>(
  onChanged: (client) => print(client),
  items: _controller.clients
      .map(
        (i) => print(i),
      )
      .toList(),
```

But `type 'List<void>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Client>>'`. I am lost already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you are printing `i`, you instead need to be returning a `DropDownMenuItem` (with a child)

For example:

```
  items: _controller.clients.map((e) => DropDownMenuItem(value: e, child: Text(e.nome))).toList(),
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it was a must. Previously I faced a similar error message even with `DropdownMenuItem`.